# Duplicate Notifications for Multiple Apps

Tags: notifications

For some reason I have been receiving duplicate notifications for many apps that offer push notifications (Amazon, Xbox)

How can I find out the cause of this issue?

Here is an example of the problem

[image]

Comment: The first one, with the Amazon "smile" is clearly from your shopping app. The second may also be from Amazon, at a different phase of the fulfillment process. If you long-click on the "duplicate - which is clearly a different message", the AppInfo may lead you to the source of the message.

Comment: They are both the same message. The first one is just expanded. I only have 1 amazon app. The same thing happens with the Xbox app and a few others

Comment: You can try the app [mentioned here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/154425/131553). By looking at the source / time stamp you can get an insight. It could well be that the Amazon app is sending twice- time stamp should clarify. If the source of different, this app may also help

Comment: @Bijan did you ever get this solved?  I've had the same problem with a handful of apps.  I used a notification logger/inspector and the only difference between the notifications is a very slight change in the timestamp.  Every other detail is identical.

Comment: No, I believe it resolved itself for me