# What is this mysterious blue dot?

Tags: htc, google-maps

[image]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

It pops up randomly when I'm using my phone. However, it ALWAYS pops up when I open Google maps. It then seems to emulate a repeated clicking motion, which freezes my phone to the point I have to do a hard restart.

I am using am HTC One m8

(I'm not sure about this but I'm pretty sure I saw a literal mouse cursor come out of the blue dot one day)

I'm naming it the BDOD (Blue Dot Of Death)

Comment: That blue dot indicates [your location](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/2839911?hl=en&ref_topic=3137761&visit_id=1-636184483413640268-1217702198&rd=3), which is getting initialised when you open map app

Comment: It is different, believe me. Anytime it appears in maps I have to do a hard reboot a few minutes later. It also pops up when I'm NOT in maps

Comment: Maybe peel app as mentioned here ? http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/640087-what-heck-floating-app-just-showed-up-today.html

Comment: If that didn't help, try using the app mentioned in this solution to find out if it is caused by an app http://android.stackexchange.com/a/154425/131553