# What does it mean an ugly pop-up with an smiley face on my lock screen?

Tags: lock-screens, popup

I've been getting pop-ups in the lock screen of my "Huawei Honor 6X" like this:

[image: screenshot]

The notifications appear at random times. There is nothing else on the pop-up other than the smiley face made of ASCII characters and an OK button. The UI does not even look genuine.

Any idea what does it mean or what could it be creating these messages?

It is running EMUI version 5.0.1, Android version 7.0 and Android's November 6 2017 security patch.

UPDATE: The *Notification History* app did not register any app producing this pop-up. Her is another screenshot of the pop-up.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked for an app named [Google Opinion Rewards](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.paidtasks) on your device? That's what the *notification* mentions. Or are you rather asking about the *dialog* at the bottom? (For terms, see [Popups, dialogs, notifications, toasts: what's the difference?](/q/52789/16575) :) In the latter case, the app @beeshyams mentioned probably won't help much.

Comment: @beeshyams "ugly pop-up with an smiley face" certainly rather applies to the dialog at the bottom of the screen. Didn't know that "notification history" covers those as well, as the name rather suggests "notifications".

Comment: Yeah, the *Google Opinion Rewards* notification is unrelated. The Smiley face appears regardless of what other notifications I have in the lock screen. I'm trying *Notification history* now. Thanks.

Comment: @beeshyams not yet, the smiley face has not appeared in the last two days. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: @beeshyams Unfortunately the Notification History app did not register what app launched the smiley face pop-up.

Comment: Sorry Typo. Meant try the *Toaster* app mentioned here https://android.stackexchange.com/a/154425/131553

Answer (score 1):

I've also started getting these and can't help but notice that you are also roaming with Telcel so my best guess is that these are USSD code dialogs from Telcel, basically it looks like they're either running some tests or having fun with it