# How to stop apps from asking permission about learning contacts?

Tags: contacts, notifications, settings

I've been getting an overlay notification on many apps (Textra, Dropbox, Instagram, others) whenever I try to exit out of it (usually hitting the back button). The notification text is:

> Did you know?
>
> We can learn your contacts and give you the choice to quickly contact your friends. We just need your permission first
>
> Never |  Maybe Later | Cool!

[Edit - screenshot: https://prnt.sc/iklfbt ]

I hit "Never" every single time, but apparently the word "never" has lost something in translation since it comes up repeatedly.

I've searched Google and found no reference to this message.

How do I get it to stop?

Comment: I have Dropbox installed but never saw this. Wondering if the notification is from some other app. Try installing apps mentioned in comments of this [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/191545/131553) to verify